# How can I copy an array to clipboard in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently looking for a methode to copy a 1D array to clipboard by using excel vba. So far, I already fail by copying only one string to the clipboard. What I did is:

First: I included the "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" to my project

Second: I tried to copy the strText string to the clipboard by using the following code.

```
Sub copyToClipboard()
   Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject       
   strText= "1"
   objData.SetText strText
   objData.PutInClipboard

   objData.GetFromClipboard
   resultString = objData.GetText
End Sub
```

If I paste the clipboard to a text Editor I get some funny symbols. If I check the content of resultString, I get "??".

---

EDIT: As mentionded below, I only get the "??" if I debug the code. A normal run is giving the expected output. Here is an image of the output window[image: The second output line is while debuging the code, the first one is a normal run]

The second output line is while debuging the code, the first one is a normal run.

Comment: What is objData?

Comment: Sorry I forget to copy one line. Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to find "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library", but it's also possible to create a UserForm inside your Workbook (The UserForm can be ignored then). Then use this code:

```
Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject

'Load Test to Clipboard
objData.SetText "TEST"
objData.PutInClipboard

'Get Text from Clipboard
objData.GetFromClipboard
Debug.Print objData.GetText
```

Then, to load an Array to the Clipboard, use something like this:

```
Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
'Join combines all Array items to one string with the specified delimiter
objData.SetText Join(ARRAY, ",") 'ARRAY is your Array-Variable, "," is your delimiter
objData.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunatly your code gave the same output as my code befor. Output window shows "??" :-/  To make it more curio, I figured out, that the code only print "??" if i run it in debug mode. In normal mode I get the "TEST". Why?

Comment: @Stefan this is really weird

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run into what is described here
[DataObject .setText and .putInClipboard sequence puts invalid data (Hex 63 characters) in clipboard](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48e8c30c-24ee-458e-a873-a4e6e13f5926/dataobject-settext-and-putinclipboard-sequence-puts-invalid-data-hex-63-characters-in-clipboard?forum=isvvba)